# Why Nextjs13 does not recognize auth route and give 404 error?

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, backend, strapi

I am working on a project that is based on NextJs v13 and uses Strapi v4 as the backend. I have a separate layout for the site, login, and dashboard. I worked on the login section and used NextAuth for authentication. But when I submit the login form, it does not recognize the authentication route and redirects to the `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error` route.
The error
`GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error 404 (Not Found)`

This is my project folder structure.

[image]

This is the submission code.

```
 const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      email: e.target.email.value,
      password: e.target.password.value,
    });
    if (result.ok) {
      router.replace('/');
      return;
    }
    alert('Credential is not valid');
  };
```

This is the [...nextauth].j code:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { signIn } from '../../../../services/auth';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Sign in with Email',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        
        if (credentials == null) return null;
       
        try {
          const { user, jwt } = await signIn({
            email: credentials.email,
            password: credentials.password,
          });
          return { ...user, jwt };
        } catch (error) {
          // Sign In Fail
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      session.id = token.id;
      session.jwt = token.jwt;
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      const isSignIn = user ? true : false;
      if (isSignIn) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.jwt = user.jwt;
      }
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    },
  },
});
```

And this the auth.js code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const strapiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL;

export async function signIn({ email, password }) {
  const res = await axios.post(`${strapiUrl}/api/auth/local`, {
    identifier: email,
    password,
  });
  return res.data;
}
```

I searched alot to solve this problem but unfotunately I could not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In nextjs 13, we can not receive the api requests like nextjs 12, you need to create a file called `route.js`, inside the file you can receive different types of requests like `POST`, `GET`, `PUT...`

In your case, create a file name it auth.js or any name you prefer, move your current nextauth.js file inside this and export it. example:

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Sign in",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "example@example.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
       
        if (credentials == null) return null;
   
        try {
           const { user, jwt } = await signIn({
               email: credentials.email,
               password: credentials.password,
              });
               return { ...user, jwt };

           } catch (error) {
             // Sign In Fail
             return null;
           }
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

then create a folder `[...nextauth]` under `/api/auth` and define your `route.js` file like this

> src/app/api/auth/[…nextauth]/route.ts

```
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

// import the authOptions you have created inside the auth.js file
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

you can add more options to your authOptions, this one was a sample of what you need to do.
[Reference](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization)